# Non-English characters are not imported using SSIS or Visual Studio Deploy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, visual-studio-2010

I'm having problems with importing data into a SQL Server 2008 database.

If I execute the following statement in SSMS, it works fine.

```
INSERT INTO 
    [dbo].[ObjectiveRatingTranslation]
( 
    [ObjectiveRatingId]
,   [TranslationId]
,   [Abbreviation]
,   [RateName]
,   [Description]
,   [CreatedBy]
,   [CreatedOn]
,   [ModifiedBy]
,   [ModifiedOn]
)
VALUES
(
    3
,   29
,   N'O / T'
,   N'På målet'
,   N'Målet har slutförts i enlighet med detta förväntningar. Uppfyller de slutprodukter som definieras. Det förväntas att de flesta mål bör vara Topplista på denna nivå.'
,   0
,   '2012-03-27T11:49:43.2300000'
,   0
,   '2012-03-27T11:49:43.2300000'
)
```

If I have this statement in  a script file that is being executed by VS 2010, Database, Deploy.  The data gets imported as

```
P� m�let | M�let har slutf�rts i enlighet med detta f�rv�ntningar. Uppfyller de slutprodukter som definieras. Det f�rv�ntas att de flesta m�l b�r vara Topplista p� denna niv�.
```

Same type of problem happens with SSIS on import to. I'm sure there must be some kind of setting that can be changed, but I"m not sure what.

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure the data is being imported like that and it's not a presentation issue? Reason I ask, is when certain fonts can't render a given glyph, they'll use a box placeholder.

Comment: No question is silly. :)  The UI is SSMS and when the data is inserted using the insert command from a query window, it display correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the file is UTF8/Unicode and not ASCII?

Comment: Is there way to make it UTF8/Unicode from Visual Studio? I'm able to do it with Notepad++.   That was the problem.  (Hang's head in shame.)

Answer (score 1):

The data types of the columns you are inserting the text into should be set to nvarchar.